# Running .bat file from EC2 using AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am currently working on project, on that I am having a bat file in EC2 and I want to run that file via AWS-lambda so that that file can transfer S3 data files.
Please help me with it. 
 I am using python language.

Comment: What's a "bat file?"  Are you talking about a Windows `.bat` (batch) file?

Comment: yes I am talking about that .
Sorry for the incomplete question I am new into this

Comment: Okay, well, a `.bat` file runs in Windows, but Lambda does not run under Windows, so you will need to write a script to accomplish the same purpose as the `.bat` file but in a language supported under Lambda, such as [Python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model.html), which you mentioned.  Hopefully, you are beyond that point, but it is not clear what you are asking.  "Please help me with it" is not a sufficiently specific question that we can answer here.  Consider editing your question for the specific programming related issue you're experiencing.

Comment: please acknowledge. I understand that you have some files on the `EC2` that need to be uploaded to `S3` and for that you have the `.bat` file. If that's the case I would like you to add more details on what you system does, how and how often you need to upload files from `EC2` to `S3`. Something looks bad here and I may suggest you a different way to solve you problem.

Comment: @johni , You are right at your place .
But I am trying to run a batch file which is located at EC2 using lambda function.
That is what my concern , if you can help me with that.....

Comment: @nikhilbhawsar I see. well in that case, you would have to open a socket that listens to, for example, `HTTP` calls and executes the `.bat` file when receiving such calls. If that idea suits you, I'll extend this idea and put some piece of code that does that.

Comment: @johni looks cool 
that should help.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this via the [AWS SSM service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-cli.html) which allows you to run commands on EC2 instances remotely.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to run a server on the `EC2` that listens to, for example, `http` calls and runs the `.bat` file for each request.

The simplest script for doing that in `nodejs` would look like this:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const BAT_PATH = 'c:\\path\\to\\file.bat';

let express = require('express');
let exec = require('child_process').exec;
let app = express();

app.get('/exec', (req, res) => {
    exec(BAT_PATH, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

        // print stdout of executing process
        console.log(stdout);

        // print stderr of executing process
        console.log(stderr);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on *:${PORT}`);
});
```

If you're a `python` guy, I'm sure you'll know how to translate this code.

As for your `lambda`, the only addition is to send `http GET` request to `ec2-ip:3000/exec`.

Don't forget to open the relevant port in the Security Group that your `EC2` is bound to.

Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Will go with it ...

Comment: please don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem.